# SwiftUI Parent view not updating after state change

Tags: swiftui, combine

I am working on a niche workout app. The flow is similar to the built in app, but a little more complicated.

I have the following code at the top level:

```
@main
struct WatchApp: App {
    
    @WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor(ExtensionDelegate.self) var delegate
    @StateObject var coordinator = SessionCoordinator()
    @StateObject var permissions = PermissionsViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                switch coordinator.workout.state {
                // ✅ Works on load
                // ❌ Doesn't reload when user changes state back to `notStarted`

                case .notStarted:
                     StartView() 
                        .sheet(isPresented: $permissions.showPermissionsPrompt, content: {
                            PermissionsView(permissions: permissions)
                        })
                // ✅ Works
                case .countingDown:
                    CountdownView() 
                // ✅ Works    
                case .paddling, .paused:
                    WorkoutOrAlertView() 
                // ✅ Works    
                case .saving, .ended:
                    SummaryView()
                    
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(coordinator)
            
        }
    }
}
```

in the SummaryView there is a button which changes the state to notStarted
`coordinator.workout.state = .notStarted`

**This does NOT reload the start view as expected from the case statement.**

The `coordinator` and the `workout` are `ObservableObjects`:

```
class SessionCoordinator: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published public var workout: WorkoutSession {
        didSet {
            DDLogVerbose("‍ workout changed")
        }
    }
```

```
class WorkoutSession: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    ....
    @Published var state = WorkoutSessionState.notStarted {
        didSet {
            DDLogVerbose("Workout state changed from: \(oldValue) to: \(state)")
        }
    }
```

So in summary, everything works as you would expect:
✅ Start a workout
✅ Show countdown if required
✅ Run workout
✅ End workout and get a summary
❌ Changing state to `.notStarted` does not reload `StartView()`

So my questions are:

- why doesn't this work?
- how can I debug it further?
- is this architecture with the top level `switch` the best way or should a different approach be used?

Comment: What happens if you encapsulate that switch statement within its own View?

Comment: @jnpdx if I create a `WorkoutView` where the `coordinator` is passed in as an `@ObjservedObject` everything behaves the same as it does now

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `@Published` property that holds a reference type, then this is only going to send `objectWillChange` when you set a new instance of the reference type. It doesn't matter if the property you changed is published - nothing in your code is listening to changes on that object.

If you genuinely want your coordinator to publish every time a property of the session changes, then you should manually observe and re-publish object will change. However, that is likely to lead to over-publishing and excessive re-rendering, particularly since this is a top-level object.

A better solution is to create a container view, which observes the session:

```swift
struct WorkoutView: View {
    @ObservedObject var workoutSession: WorkoutSession

    var body: some View {
        switch workoutSession.state {
        //... all your cases here
        }
    }
}
```

Then your original view would be:

```swift
NavigationView {
    WorkoutView(workoutSession: coordinator.workout) 
}
```

This means you'll get a new WorkoutView whenever the instance of the workout changes, and that workout view will monitor the state.

You'll need to either inject the permissions into the environment or pass that as an observed object as well so it can be picked up.

Oh - and using switch statements in a view like this? Fantastic. The best way!

Comment: So you mean that `switch workout.state` would observe changes, but `switch coordinator.workout.state` wouldn't?  I never see "‍ workout changed" output to the logs, but maybe that is a bug in the logging. But I do see the screens update every time the workout state changes, apart from at the end. The child views need to have both the workout session and another object on the coordinator, that's why I'm using a coordinator, so I guess I would pass them both down as @ObservedObjects. I will experiment with your solution and see how I go, thank you.

Comment: also, if I don't have access to the coordinator in the child views I can call `coordinator.pause()` etc. so should I pass in a reference to the coordinator, the workout, and the extra object? It feels like a bad smell to be passing all three around everywhere? I guess sometimes needs must

Comment: Don't think of the `switch` as observing the changes, that's not what is happening. Your `WatchApp` struct owns a @StateObject of the coordinator, and will re-evaluate its body after that object sends `objectWillChange`, which will cause the switch to be re-run. The coordinator will only send `objectWillChange` when one of its published properties changes. If the screens are updating then perhaps some other property of the coordinator is being updated?

Comment: Owning @StateObjects at a top level and putting them into the environment so they can be accessed at lower levels is a fairly common practice. As long as you are carefully considering the scope (i.e. does it _really_ need to be initiated all the way up here?) I think it's fine. There's always a balance to be struck between few, large observable objects and innumerable smaller ones.

Comment: "perhaps some other property of the coordinator is being updated?" this was the thing that made it all make sense for me, altho the rest of this comment is invaluable too. How bad would something like this be at the top level `@State private var workoutState: WorkoutSessionState = .notStarted` coupled with `.onReceive(coordinator.workout.$state) { newState in workoutState = newState }`. Then the switch is on `switch workoutState`. This works, and I don't think it leads to lots of re-rendering, but it is an extra source of truth

Comment: You could do that approach, but have a state var that just  marks the view as dirty, and always pull from the correct source of truth - `@State private var dirtyWhenToggled = false`, `onReceive(coordinator.workout.$state) { _ in dirtyWhenToggled.toggle() }`

Comment: oooo! so neat, love it! I'm not really sure whether to mark this answer as correct (more a reflection of the question than the answer), but I'm going to award bounty because you have helped me a huge amount